# Don't keep inline styles or tag attributes in clipboard when user copies text content from a contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

HTML divs with `contentEditable` keep any styles applied to the text when a user highlights and copies.

I have a `contentEditable` div where text inside the div becomes decorated with underlines via inline styles on spans of text. Currently if a user highlights the text and copies, if they later paste it into another contentEditable - for example, Gmail's email compose box - it keeps the underlines.

So for example, a line of text may look like (in the DOM):

```
<span class="underline" 
 id="id-1" 
 style="box-shadow: white 0px 0px 0px 0px inset, 
 rgb(1, 2, 3) 0px -2px 0px 0px inset; 
 background-color: transparent;">This is an example.</span>
```

And once it has been copied and then pasted into Gmail, it's added to the DOM as:

```
<span class="gmail-underline" 
 id="gmail-id-1" 
 style="box-shadow: white 0px 0px 0px 0px inset, 
 rgb(1, 2, 3) 0px -2px 0px 0px inset; 
 background-color: transparent;">This is an example.</span>
```

Which means within Gmail's editor, which is also contentEditable, the underline from the original div remains.

Gmail does some processing here to add `gmail-` to the `id` and `class`, but the point is, that data was available on the clipboard.

How can I make it so that when a user does a regular copy from the original div, highlighting the text and pressing CTRL+C or right click-> copy, they only get the text (i.e. `innerText`) in the div and none of the markup is retained?

This appears to only be an issue copying between contentEditables - if the above sentence were copied to, say, Microsoft Word, it would just be "This is an example.", no HTML around it.

I believe something can be done with intercepting copy events and possibly using `document.execCommand` to copy, but am not sure how to do it. I've seen similar questions about *pasting* into contentEditables, but haven't found anything about stopping it at the source when copying.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sharing your findings or are you looking for a solution, its not clear from your question.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution, I only have found a few hints as to what may be part of the solution, but haven't been able to get it to actually work myself.